# golang scan a line of numbers from sdin

Tags: go

I'm trying to read input from stdin like

```
3 2 1<ENTER>
```

and save it in a list of ints. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
nums = make([]int, 0)
var i int
for {
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&i)
    if err != nil {
        if err==io.EOF { break }
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    nums = append(nums, i)
}
```

at the moment the program never leaves the for-loop. I can't find an easy way to check for a newline character in the documentation. how would i do this?

Edit:

Since I know that there will almost certainly be four numbers, I tried the following:

```
var i0,i1,i2,i3 int
fmt.Scanf("%d %d %d %d\n", &i0, &i1, &i2, &i3)
```

but this only scanned the first number and then exited the program. I'm not sure if that's because of the z-shell I'm using.

Edit:

To clarify, the program will pause and ask for the user to input a list of n numbers separated by spaces and terminated with a newline. these numbers should be stored in an array.

Comment: `Ctrl+D` will send EOF to your program

Comment: If you don't know how many numbers there will be, why not scan the line in all at once?

Comment: IMHO it's unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to 1. read *all* of the numbers in a file (which looks like the first code in your question), 2. read *all* the numbers on one line (the code in your answer), or 3. read *exactly* n numbers from one line (which looks like the second code block in your question), or 4. something else? If you tell us *exactly* what you want, I'm confident the community can help.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I decided to bring out the large bufio hammer and solve it like this:

```
in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
line, err := in.ReadString('\n')
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
strs := strings.Split(line[0:len(line)-1], " ")
nums := make([]int, len(strs))
for i, str := range strs {
    if nums[i], err = strconv.Atoi(str); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

It does seem like an awful lot of code, but it works.

Comment: I think the code you've pasted is incomplete. There should be another '}' at the end to close the for loop. It'd be nice for the `if nums[] ... {...}` to be indented too. It looks like this is reading all of the numbers on one line. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yepp, that's what i wanted :) I'd have thought there would be a way to read it with something like `var args []interface{}; fmt.Scanln(args...)` but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Did you just pass an empty interface slice? The documentation (predictably) states: "All arguments to be scanned must be either pointers to basic types or implementations of the Scanner interface."

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did :) It didn't like `var args []string; fmt.Scanln(args...)`. I'll dig out the error message

Comment: That's because []string is a different type from []interface{}.

Again, the documentation says you must pass pointers to basic types. You're not passing any pointers, so you're not getting any results.

If you pass this:

var i, j, k int;
fmt.Scanln([]interface{&i, &j, &k}...}

You'll get better results. You'll find those results in vars i, j, k.

I think the source of the confusion is that you're trying to leave open the question of how many numbers there are on a line. fmt.Scanln isn't built that way. You must pass n pointers to read n numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fscanln

Something like

```
ok := func(err error) { if err != nil { panic(err) } }

for {
  var i, j, k int
  _, err := fmt.Fscanln(io.Stdin, &i, &j, &k)
  ok(err)
  fmt.Println(i, j, k)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use "bufio" package with the "scan()" method.
Following is the code where I'm reading two lines from "stdin" and storing the lines into an array.
Hope this helps you.

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func ReadInput() []string{

    var lines []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
        //count, _ := strconv.Atoi(lines[0])
        if len(lines) == 2 { break }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    return lines
}

func main(){

    lines   := ReadInput()
    count ,_ := strconv.Atoi(lines[0])
    num := strings.Fields(lines[1])
    if count != len(num) { os.Exit(0) }
 // Do whatever you want here
}
```

Two lines will be accepted. First line will have a count. Second line will have all the numbers. You can modify the same code as per your requirement.

Example:

```
3
1 5 10
```