# Fast method to take input separated by space [Golang]

Tags: go

I'm trying to take fast input through `scanner.Bytes` and I'm it converting to int. The problem is : input provided is single line spaced elements ( like an array ) and `scanner.Bytes` reads it as a whole and converts it into int. How can I use a Splitfunction on the bytes read!

```
func main()  {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var t int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &t)

    for o := 0; o < t; o++ {
        scanner.Scan()
        //scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords())
        val := toInt(scanner.Bytes())
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

func toInt(buf []byte) (n int) {
    for _, v := range buf {
        n = n*10 + int(v-'0')
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Pass https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanWords into https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Split and then the scanner should scan the input by words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang scan a line of numbers from sdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017547/golang-scan-a-line-of-numbers-from-sdin)

Comment: @Anuruddha It's not because here I'm talking about fast input scanning.

Comment: give us some sample input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just try something like

```
func main()  {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        val, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The default [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) (with the default split function) breaks the input into lines with line termination stripped. If you want to break the input into words, you have to set a different split function using the [`Scanner.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Split) method.

There is a ready split function for breaking words: [`bufio.ScanWords()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanWords). We can see this function commented in your code.

But know that `Scanner.Split()` method expects a *function value*. You do not need to call the split function, the scanner will call it to break the input data. You just have to pass the function value, which you can do so without calling it, without appending `()` after the function name, e.g.:

```
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
```

Also note that you only have to do this once, and you can only do this once, before starting to scan the input, so move this line above the `for` loop:

```
var t int
fmt.Scanf("%d", &t)

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
for o := 0; o < t; o++ {
    scanner.Scan()
    val := toInt(scanner.Bytes())
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

Now running the app, and entering the following lines:

```
3
1 2 3
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

Also note that [`Scanner.Scan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan) returns a `bool` value indicating if scanning was successful and you may process the token. You should use this return value and not rely on the user inputting valid data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is `3 65 65 65` and `3` is the number of following bytes, then this works:

```
func main() {
    var t int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &t)
    values := make([]byte, t)
    buf := make([]interface{}, t)
    for i := 0; i < t; i++ {
        buf[i] = &values[i]
    }
    fmt.Scanln(buf...)

    // test
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", values)
}
```

The *test* output is `[65 65 65]`.